# Include MenuBar from seperated file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I am stack trying to include MenuBar from separate file and trying to connect with function

I include some code that I have the same problem

foo.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import os
import sys
from foomenu import menu

FROM_MAIN, _ = loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "SalesGui.ui"))


class Main(QMainWindow, FROM_MAIN):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.MyMenu = menu(self)
        self.MyMenu.NewProduct.triggered.connect(self.NewProduct())

    def NewProduct(self):
        print("foo")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as why:
        print(why)
```

and foomenu.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenu


def menu(self):
    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('FooMenu')

    NewProduct = QAction(QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'Foo', self)
    NewProduct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    NewProduct.setStatusTip('FooAction')
    fileMenu.addAction(NewProduct)
```

When Trying to connect the "NewProduct" button with "New Product" function I get the following error

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'NewProduct'`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenu

#from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
#from foomenu import menu
#FROM_MAIN, _ = loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "SalesGui.ui"))

def menu(self):
    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('FooMenu')

    self.NewProduct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Foo', self)  # 'icons/exit.png'  # + self
    self.NewProduct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    self.NewProduct.setStatusTip('FooAction')
    fileMenu.addAction(self.NewProduct)

    return self.NewProduct                                                         # +++

class Main(QMainWindow):#, FROM_MAIN):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.MyMenu = menu(self)

#        self.MyMenu.NewProduct.triggered.connect(self.funcNewProduct)             # - ()
        self.MyMenu.triggered.connect(self.funcNewProduct)                         # +

    def funcNewProduct(self):
        print("foo")
        qApp.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is much more elegant to subclass and setup the menubar in this another python file then import and instance this class in your file that holds the Main class.

In the MyMenu class you can binding the signal a socket locally that can provide from here the sender object for the parent class.

BTW you can iterate over the action object of the menubar/menus but it is much more harder to maintain and control then the explicit describe where to connect the potential different actions.

Menu.py:

```
    class MyMenu(QMenuBar):

        new_product_clicked = Signal(object)

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyMenu, self).__init__(parent)

            file_menu = QMenu("File menu", self)
            new_product_action = QAction('Foo', self)
            new_product_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
            new_product_action.setStatusTip('FooAction')
            new_product_action.triggered.connect(self.new_product_clicked)
            file_menu.addAction(new_product_action)

            self.addMenu(file_menu)

        def new_product_clicked(self):
            """ Call a method from the parent class. """
            self.new_product_clicked.emit(self.sender())
```

Main.py:

```
from Menu import MyMenu


class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        my_menu = MyMenu(self)
        self.setMenuBar(my_menu)
        self.my_menu.new_product_clicked.connect(self.product_clicked)

    def product_clicked(self, action):
        """ Socket for the clicked action """
        clicked_action = action
        print clicked_action.text()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your Signal/Slot is not set up correctly - in fact other than you calling them that they are not a Signal nor a Slot -- just a direct function call -- Heck even your actual Signal is not Slotted although yes it can be done that way -- but explicit is better than lazy coding ;)

Comment: yes, right, it should be better with an another signal emit. i have modified.